# MVC 4/C# :Run ajax call when ModelState.IsValid is true

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to call api that do a check on the database for customer login if the login succeed it will return alert with that, i also applies dataAnnotation in the model.

```
public class Customers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Customer's Name")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is the view i used:

```
@model CodeFirstCustomers.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginProcess", "Login"))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 alert alert-warning">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customers.Name)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(c=>c.Customers.Name,new { @class="form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c=>c.Customers.Name)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customers.Password)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Customers.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customers.Password)
                        </div>
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <button value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

This is the ajax call, the url is an api that will take customer as parameter and then check if username and password is true it will return Ok or not found.

```
 @section scripts{
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#savedata").on("click", function (evt) {
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        // var form = $("form");

                        if ($(form).valid()) {
                            var data = {
                                Name: $("#userid").val(),
                                Password: $("#password").val()
                            }
                            $.ajax({

                                url: "/api/login",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                success: function () {
                                    alert("Success");

                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    alert("Fail");
                                }
                            });//Ajax call

                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });//savedata
                });
            </script>

        }
```

this is the api that will perform the check:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public LoginController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        //POST: api/login
       [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult ValidateCustomer(Customers customer)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var checks = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == customer.Name && c.Password == customer.Password);
            if (checks == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {

                return Ok();
            }

        }
    }
```

and this is the LoginProcess action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LoginProcess(Customers customers)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel
            {
                Customers = customers

            };
            return View("loginPage", viewModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

API login:

```
public class LoginValidationController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public LoginValidationController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult ValidateCustomer(Customers customer)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var checks = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == customer.Name && c.Password == customer.Password);
            if (checks == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {

                return Ok();
            }

        }

    }

the is validation is working perfectly, but how can i execute the ajax code
```

after the validation succeed using modelState.IsValid?

Comment: do you want to execute a script, when it redirects to "Index" action on "Home" Controller from "LoginProcess" action

Comment: @RonyLoud  simply i want to run the script after check the ModelState and the if the script success i want to  redirect to index, the login check is essentially  done by ajax call

Comment: If you want to Invoke "LoginProcess" method after the first one returns Ok then you can have another ajax call in the Success of first ajax call

Comment: @GirishSakhare i didn't understand what you'r trying to say, but if i use"LoginProcess" to send the model to it in order to check modelState, then how can i call ajax script to check the login in the api?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you do not need Ajax in Login page. Just add `type="submit"` to ***button***.

If you can make it work, you can go fancy with Ajax later.

```
@model CodeFirstCustomers.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginProcess", "Login"))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 alert alert-warning">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        ...
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(CustomerViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Validate crendential here. If valid user, return to Home.
        if (true)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password.");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

You can look at Login Page sample code at [my GitHub project](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L33).

Comment: but i need the ajax call to api in order to validate crendential in the api.

Comment: In your scenario, Ajax call at login page doesn't make sense, because you are redirecting user to a new page anyway unless you are developing true SPA site.

Comment: Ok, deal ... if i validate credential in the api, then on success i will redirect user to another page using i solved my problem, but what about client side validation if the user doesn't enter neither password or username?

Comment: `client side validation if the user doesn't enter neither password or username` For that, you need to use [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/).

Comment: I know i asked you many times, but i really didn't get the answer, i already use Unobtrusive validation in my bundle but it doesn't work too. I updated my question by adding the api that i called from ajax please refer to it

Comment: Unobtrusive validation is way out of your original question. First of all, you need to install [Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/) via NuGet. Then add to bundle config like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs#L12). You can download my working sample code from [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin), and click Submit button without entering username and password.